# linux sending command to existing screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I have created a screen "myscreen", and inside that screen I navigated to a folder that contains a python file test.py, that simply prints something. Then I detached the screen, and now I'm trying to send a command to it to run my script. So I tried the following command:

```
screen -S myscreen -X stuff python test.py `echo -ne '\015'`
```

No errors there, but when I opened my screen to see the output there, I saw nothing - the screen was blank. I tried another approach: I created a shell file, where I wrote:

```
screen -r myscreen
python test.py
```

But the result was the same and nothing was printed. What are the reasons that both attempts failed and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Update:

I also tried this which didn't work:

```
screen -X select myscreen
screen -X readreg p <( echo python test.py )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do it like you do, you send the commands to the screen itself,
not in the terminal running inside it.

How can you send the commands inside the terminal?

Use `readreg` and `paste`. Here I send data from `/tmp/file` into the screen 1:

```
$ screen -X select 1
$ screen -X readreg p /tmp/file
$ screen -X paste p
```

If you have no file with the data,
you can use process substitution, like that:

```
$ screen -X readreg p <( echo python test.py )
```

Comment: Mister_L: You must run `paste p` after that + do `select 1` if want to paste into the terminal 1 (it is 0 by default).

Comment: @IgorChubin Hmm, my version of screen doesn't seem to like process substitution (it says "no slurp: no such file or directory"), but it works with a temp file.

Comment: @T.J.It is the shell, not screen, who doesn't understand it. But does it work with the file?